# Bucket number for null key in hashmap

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, bucket

In a hashmap what would be the bucket number of null key? I am Trying to learn internals of hashmap if any one can give me good video tutorials it would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like trying to solve issue sitting on interview

Answer (score 1):

`HashMap`, handles `null key` differently. 
For the `null key`, default value of **hashcode is 0** and the `first bin/bucket will be used to place it as per the HashMap implementation`

From HashMap class

```
 static final int hash(Object key) {
        int h;
        return (key == null) ? 0 : (h = key.hashCode()) ^ (h >>> 16);
    }
```

> Internally HashMap maintains array of Entry class(internal class of
>   HashMap which is used to store data) which is also called as Bucket.
>   Entry class contains key, value, nextElement, hash-value variables.
>
> Data with null key is stored at Bucket location 0(array index 0 of
>   Entry array). Hash value is also zero for null key.

[Source](http://shava28.blogspot.in/2013/06/java-storing-null-key-in-hashmap.html)

Comment: *If you don't aware of bucket,then keep away man....* - is the response you get when you try to tell the OP the same thing. LMAO

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar Yes i have gone thru comments, i have flagged it

Comment: He is like lkg student.Don't know how to talk.sitting here to demotivate others.